# Unlock the Screen Programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, unlock, keyguard, android-powermanager

I have a share button in the `GCM notification`. On click of the share button, I need to launch share intent. Everything works perfectly. Only problem that I'm facing is `Lollipop` lock screen feature. When I click share button from lock screen, my intent dialog appears below the lock screen and user has to unlock the screen to see the dialog. I want to unlock the screen programatically, when share button is clicked.

I tried with Power Manager, But all it's `wakeClock` flags are deprecated and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.Flag_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`is recommened to use.  But I'm not using activity here. I'm using `broadcastReciever context`. and hence I cannot use `getWindow()`method.

I also tried with `KeyguardManager`. But even `disableKeyguard()` is deprectated.

I cannot use the `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`, as this should be used, if we want to perform any action after screen is unlocked.

i had used below intent to programmatically close the notification tray:

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        mContext.sendBroadcast(it);
```

Is there a similar intent, that can be broadcasted to unlock the screen

**Updated Code using DevicePolicyManager:**

```
public static void handleShareBtnClick(Context context, String message) {
    GcmHelper helper = new GcmHelper();
    helper.shareMessage(context, message);
    if(Utility.isLollypopAndAbove()){
          helper.unlockLockScreen();
    }
    helper.launchShareforForAlert();

}



   public void unlockLockScreen(){
        DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyMngr= (DevicePolicyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName compName=new ComponentName(mContext, DeviceAdminReceiver.class);
        if(!devicePolicyMngr.isAdminActive(compName))
            devicePolicyMngr.removeActiveAdmin(compName);
    }
```

Even after using DevicePolicyManager, It's not unlocking my screen

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Add below code in your activity before `setContentView(R.layout.example);`

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Step 2: Lock your mobile, then you will see activity in which you have added this code.
This will work even though your mobile is locked with pattern lock. This will work like a charm.

Comment: I actually tried this and it works. I used it for a push notification to open a screen automatically, even if the screen is turned off and locked. Thanks.

Comment: Works well, thanks!!, just to complement, some of this code is now deprecated, you can handle this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277302/android-o-flag-show-when-locked-is-deprecated